# lxml stops when it encounters a missing tag

Tags: python, xml, lxml

I'm parsing some XML files to extract particular tags.  With lots of help on here, it is working with my test files.  I now have a new problem; the next file that my colleague wants me to test appears to be missing some of the tags.

This is the code that I currently have:

```
with open('output.log', 'w') as f:
   for info in root.xpath('//xmlns:ProgramInformation', namespaces=nsmap):
      crid = (info.get('programId')) # retrieve crid
      title = (info.find('.//xmlns:Title', namespaces=nsmap).text) # retrieve title
      genre = (info.find('.//xmlns:Genre/xmlns:Name', namespaces=nsmap).text) # retrieve genre
      f.write('{}|{}|{}\n'.format(crid, title, genre))
```

The 'crid' will always be present, however it seems there are some issues where title and / or genre aren't generated.  This causes everything to stop.

Is there any way to either make the code skip over the missing tags (but still write the crid) and move on to the next set, or a way to write an error in to the output file (in place of the missing title or genre).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

not as compact unfortunately, but you'll have to split it up:

```
  titlex = info.find('.//xmlns:Title', namespaces=nsmap)
  title = titlex.text if titlex != None else ''
```

Comment: Thanks for that - managed to get it working well. In the same vein, there seem to be some programs with 'illegal characters': File "D:\Nick Apps\Python 3.3.2\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 19, in encode return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_table)[0] UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u0131' in position 30: character maps to <undefined>

How can I make it ignore or recode these characters?

Comment: see the lxml documentation here: http://lxml.de/parsing.html . assuming this is during parsing? you may need to specify a different encoding during parsing.

Comment: In the end, I just had to add "encoding='utf-8'" to the output, so that it read "with open('output.log', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f:"